# how to solve PopToviewController behaviour correct in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I also done with PopToViewController with:-

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2] animated:YES];

With Below Code but when i popping toviewcontroller is slowly went to pop with midway display previous controller background with titles not pop fast as expected so kindly give me advice for it , thanks in advance for help.

[image: PopToViewController from NavigationStack]

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the Problem, The solution is :- set UIViewController Navigation Animated to NO.